# Configuration of Asterisk 13 to support WebSockets/WebRTC

Tags: websocket, webrtc, asterisk

I have a virtual machine with debian 9. I have installed Asterisk 13.14.1 through apt-get and I have configured it to have three users two of which are sip users (Zoiper APP) and the other one webrtc user (Custom app using http://jssip.net/). The custom app is very basic and uses the code the can be found in https://github.com/versatica/JsSIP. However instead of using:

```
var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://mypbxipaddress');
```

I use

```
var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('ws://mypbxipaddress');
```

The SIP users seem to work properly. However I have issue with the webrtc user, which I think is on the server side and specifically on the websocket. In the client side during the connection I receive the following error:

```
main.js:158470 WebSocket connection to 'ws://mypbxipaddress/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Furthermore, I have tried the wscat (npm package)

```
wscat -s echo -c ws://mypbxipaddress:arandomport
```

and I receive:

```
error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED mypbxipaddress:arandomport
```

Finally I have checked in

```
asterisk -rvvvvv
```

the

```
http show status
```

and I get:

```
HTTP Server Status:
Prefix:
Server: Asterisk/13.14.1~dfsg-2
Server Enabled and Bound to 0.0.0.0:8080

Enabled URI's:
/httpstatus => Asterisk HTTP General Status
/phoneprov/... => Asterisk HTTP Phone Provisioning Tool
/static/... => Asterisk HTTP Static Delivery
/ari/... => Asterisk RESTful API
/ws => Asterisk HTTP WebSocket

Enabled Redirects:
  None.
```

which indicates with /ws => Asterisk HTTP WebSocket, that the websocket is active.

Any suggestions on how I could debug it further?

Thanks
Symeon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was much simpler, as always. I had to change

```
var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('ws://mypbxipaddress:8088/ws');
```

The way I concluded to that after some searching was:

```
asterisk -rvvvvv
http show status
```

There it mentions on the "Server Enabled and Bound to mypbxipaddress:8088", which is defined in /etc/asterisk/http.conf

```
bindaddr=mypbxipaddress
bindport=8088
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try: `wscat -s echo -c ws://mypbxipaddress:8080/ws`
because: `Server Enabled and Bound to 0.0.0.0:8080` and `/ws => Asterisk HTTP WebSocket`

You can also check the if the socket is in LISTEN state:

```
netstat -lna | grep 8080
```

Answer (score -1):

1)Read more about websocket, do tcpdump.

2) Do asterisk debug

```
asterisk -r
core set debug 10
```

Comment: The core set debug 10 didn't make any difference. I didn't get any messages. However with tcpdump I received the following message which might indicate something:

05:54:53.080539 IP deviceip.54978 > PBXIP.5060: SIP: REGISTER sip:172.26.41.2;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
05:54:53.080975 IP PBXIP.80 > deviceip.35469: Flags [P.], seq 1:3325, ack 576, win 236, options [nop,nop,TS val 12025967 ecr 139793604], length 3324: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
05:54:53.081863 IP PBXIP.5060 > deviceip.54978: SIP: SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized